# How to align items in a row using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three buttons and i want to align them in a row and they should get equal space.

For example i have something like this:-

```
<div class='parent'>
  <button class='child'> Button 1 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 2 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Now i want to align all the buttons in a single row having equal space so that if i add another button in future i don't need to worry and every button will have equal space.

Comment: Have you tried anything? what does your 'child' class look like?

Comment: Flexbox is your friend  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 9):

This will work. I highly recommend you to read more about [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as this is essential for CSS styiling.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <button class='child'> Button 1 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 2 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange answer. `space-between` doesn't distribute items with even amounts of space. `space-evenly` does.

Answer (score 2):

You should study about `Flex`. Here is solution...

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
  
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <button class='child'> Button 1 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 2 </button>
  <button class='child'> Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right:1.5em;
}
```

Comment: add some description

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[Link for the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/hvdua8s1/)